# Node.js app using subdomains hangs instead of throwing 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I am using the 'subdomain' module to create two versions of my website, the 'www' or current version, and 'fa14' or archived version.

```
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

var subdomainOptions = {
    base: 'localhost',
};
app.use(require('subdomain')(subdomainOptions));

app.use('/subdomain/fa14/', express.static(__dirname + '/fa14'));
app.use('/subdomain/www/', express.static(__dirname + '/www'));


app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status('404: Page not found', 404);
});

app.listen(8888);
```

The app works exactly as expected when accessing www.localhost or fa14.localhost, but trying to access "www.localhost/INVALIDURL" or "fa14.localhost/INVALIDURL" or any other path that should 404, the connection just hangs.  It should be returning "404 page not found"

Can anyone figure out why the last route isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`res.status()` only sets the status](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.status), it does not send the response. You need to use `res.end()` to end the response or replace your `res.status()` with `res.send(404)` which sets the status code *and* ends the response in one call.

Comment: In newer versions of Express, you might get a "deprecated" warning about `res.send(400)`. Use `res.sendStatus(400)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused `res.status` with `res.send`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the differences? This answer as it stands is a bit bare.